# Syntax error updating mysql user password in mysql Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the password of user == admin, my SQL version is `Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL`

```
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| admin            |
| admin            |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
+------------------+
```

```
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('password@1234') where user='admin';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('password@1234') where user='admin'' at line 1
```

```
mysql> UPDATE user 
    -> SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('password@1234')
    -> WHERE user = 'admin' AND 
    ->       host = 'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('password@1234')
WHERE user = 'admin' AND 
      host = 'localhost'' at line 2
```

I have tried the above two and with password in place of authentication_string. It anyway should be authentication_string as the user table contain column with this only

Answer (score 1):

"user" is a reserved keyword. You need to surround it with backticks:

```
UPDATE `user`
SET `authentication_string`=PASSWORD('password@1234')
WHERE `user`='admin';
```

Comment: same error but i changed the password using this "ALTER USER dbadmin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'littlewhale';"

Comment: I think additionally the `password()` function was removed in one of the recent MySQL versions. But there are actually multiple ways to set the password now: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: there are two user for admin one for localhost and one for %, and i am only able to change password of localhost

Comment: `ALTER USER "admin"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`

Answer (score 0):

```
use mysql;
update user set user='admin' where user='root';
flush privileges;       
ALTER USER "admin"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
ALTER USER "admin"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

This is how I update the username and password. Thanks to @ghostgambler